# Христос говорит (–) будьте как дети

Tags: пунктуация, тире, цитата

Христос говорит – *будьте как дети*, и в этом "будьте"... (выделено курсивом, как в подлинном тексте)

- Возможна ли такая пунктуация: тире и цитата (роль кавычек здесь замещает выделение курсивом, это ясно)? Как объяснить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тире может предшествовать косвенной речи, обычно заменяя "что". Примеры есть у Розенталя. Тут такая же по смыслу конструкция, кавычки не нужны. А курсив помогает понять, где кончается косвенная речь.

Дополнение:
§ 45.7 Тире ставится, если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта (ср. § 44, п. 3): Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.); Иногда мне думается — надо убежать (М.Г.); …Слышит — за кустами бузины девушка хохочет (М.Г.); Тишина была такой полной и угрюмой, а небо таким душным, что мальчику казалось — раздайся хоть один только резкий звук, и в природе произойдёт что-то страшное (Кат.); Вчера на соседнем зимовье рассказывали — мед ведь человека задрал (Арб.); Слышу — опять стонет (Па— уст.); Движение приостановлено, будем надеяться — ненадолго; Кто-то скребётся, мне показалось — мышь; Но вижу — не слушает она меня; Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали — будут встречать; Они знали — будет буря; Отстань, не видишь — я занят.

Comment: Не трудно ли Вам дать ссылку?

Comment: @М_Г прямо ссылку найти сейчас не могу, но в старых ответах у меня была цитата из правила. Дополнил ею ответ.

Comment: @М_Г [Вот ссылка](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827528.html).

Comment: Да, очень интересно. Вы поколебали мою уверенность. Перечитал текст, там "будьте как дети" упомянуто второй раз и действительно "в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения". Ставлю плюс.

Answer (score 1):

**Христос говорит – *будьте как дети*...**

Предложение оформлено как БСП по Розенталю (с использование тире перед изъяснительной частью):

7. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет **изъяснительное значение** (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части **не содержится интонационного предупреждения** о последующем изложении какого-либо факта: Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.);  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

**Под интонационным предупреждением** понимается отсутствие увеличенной предупредительной паузы, характерной для двоеточия. Так Розенталь объясняет замену двоеточия тире.

Что касается **курсива**, то он используется **по оформительским правилам и стандартам, а не по правилам письма.** Для оформления прямой речи курсив **не применяется,** но может выполнять выделительную функцию в качестве **указания на дословность** сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

> Христос говорит — будьте как дети (см. Мф. 18, 3), и в этом «будьте» есть что-то знакомое, философское — быть, а не казаться. ([Анна Лелик. Как дети](http://otrok-ua.ru/sections/art/show/kak_deti.html))

Посмотрим, что написано в [Евангелии (Мф. 18, 3).](https://bible.by/verse/40/18/3/)

> Синодальный перевод:
>   и сказал: истинно говорю вам, если не обратитесь и не будете как дети, не войдете в Царство Небесное;
>
> Русского Библейского Центра
>   И сказал: «Верное слово: откажитесь от себя, будьте как дети. Без этого нет вам Царства Небесного.

1. Если слова Христа в нашем предложении переданы не дословно (см. синодальный перевод), то это БСП с изъяснительным значением. В таких предложениях ставят двоеточие. Мне не проходилось встречать тире в таких случаях.
2. Если слова Христа в нашем предложении переданы дословно (см. вариант Русского Библейского Центра), то все равно можно  считать это БСП с изъяснительным значением, которое заменяет предложение с прямой речью как более простой вариант.
3. Если слова Христа в нашем предложении переданы дословно, но использован курсив вместо кавычек, то нужно следовать правилам оформления прямой речи, а это значит нужно поставить двоеточие.

   Мой вариант един для всех трех подходов:

**Христос говорит: будьте как дети (см. Мф. 18, 3), и в этом «будьте» есть что-то знакомое, философское: быть, а не казаться.**